# Convert a JavaScript RegEx into JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, regex, safari-extension

I'm currently developing a Safari Extension which will make use of the new [webkit-content-blocker](https://www.webkit.org/blog/3476/content-blockers-first-look/) feature available in Safari 9. Now, the rules of such blockers need to be written in JSON.

The background script of my soon-to-be extension generates such JSON rules. The issue I have is that I cannot properly format a regex, whose role is to filter URLs, to be JSON compatible.

Say I need to block all images whose URL contains either "banana", "orange", or "apple". My regex would be something like:

```
var url-filter = /banana|orange|apple/g;
```

Now the blocker's rule in JSON, missing the url filtering part:

```
"action": {
   "type": "block"
    },
"trigger": {
   "url-filter": <JSON regex here>,
   "resource-type": ["image"],
   "load-type": ["third-party"]
    }
```

[UPDATED]

How can I rewrite my regex to be JSON compatible/ready, knowing that alternations are not supported ?

> **The Regular expression format**
>
> Triggers support filtering the URLs of each resource based on regular expression.
>
> The following features are supported:
>
> - Matching any character with “.”.
> - Matching ranges with the range syntax [a-b].
> - Quantifying expressions with “?”, “+” and “*”.
> - Groups with parenthesis.
>
> It is possible to use the beginning of line (“^”) and end of line (“$”) marker but they are restricted to be the first and last character of the expression. For example, a pattern like “^bar$” is perfectly valid, while “(foo)?^bar$” causes a syntax error.

[UPDATED BIS]

Given the strict CSP policy implemented by Safari and the lack of support for alternations, I finally converted my original regex into an array and then dynamically generated the JSON rules via a loop.

```
var regex = 'banana|orange|apple',
    filters = regex.split('|'),
    json_rules = [];

var Blocker = {
        build: function() {

            filters.forEach( function(filter) {
                var rule = {
                    action: {
                        'type': 'block'
                    },
                    trigger: {
                        'url-filter': filter,
                        'resource-type': ['image'],
                        'load-type': ['third-party']
                    }
                };
                json_rules.push(rule);
            });

            Blocker.set(JSON.stringify(json_rules));
        },
        init: function() {
            Blocker.build();
        },
        set: function (rule) {
            safari.extension.setContentBlocker(rule);
        }

};
```

Comment: Add the regex as _string_ in the JSON, and use this string in `new RegExp(str, 'g')`, also I presume you always want to use the global flag, so that is not needed to use in the JSON string

Comment: JSON cannot contain regexps. So, they would need to hold them as strings, as this particular API also calls for.

Comment: Easy enough... Use regexp.toString() and then eval to convert back ;) and for unsupported just check for characters inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked, the values of the filters are treated as regular expressions (for example, they show `"url-filter": "evil-tracker\\.js"` and `"url-filter": ".*"`).

The documentation also says that `url-filter` is case-insensitive, so you don't have to worry about the `i` flag you might otherwise want to use. But if you wanted a case-sensitive one, you'd add `"url-filter-is-case-sensitive": true`.

That being the case, you just put your regular expression in quotes, being sure to escape any characters that need to be escaped within a string literal (for instance, note how they used two backslashes in their `"evil-tracker\\.js"` string, in order for the regex to be `evil-tracker\.js`).

**However**: The problem with your expression is that they don't support alternations. Again, from the documentation you linked:

> The format is a strict subset of JavaScript regular expressions. Syntactically, everything supported by JavaScript is reserved but only a subset will be accepted by the parser. An unsupported expression results in a parse error.
>
> The following features are supported:
>
> - Matching any character with “.”.
> - Matching ranges with the range syntax [a-b].
> - Quantifying expressions with “?”, “+” and “*”.
> - Groups with parenthesis.
>
> It is possible to use the beginning of line (“^”) and end of line (“$”) marker but they are restricted to be the first and last character of the expression. For example, a pattern like “^bar$” is perfectly valid, while “(foo)?^bar$” causes a syntax error.

Note that they don't accept `|` (alternation).

That tells me you'll need three rules: One for `banana`, one for `orange`, and one for `apple`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The url-filter you suggest was the first I tried when writing the blocker's rule. However, I get an error whenever I load the extension with such a format: "JSON compilation failed". Using the global one ".*" works, so I know the error comes from the regex.

Comment: @flo: Later in the docs we see why: They don't support alternation. I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes, that's my problem :) [sorry for the misunderstanding, updated my question to make it clearer]. The thing is that my list of words is large, meaning that writing rules for each one of them will make the whole thing ugly and over-complicated...

Comment: @flo: Unfortunately, with them not supporting alternations, you're going to have a long list. You may sometimes be able to combine things with character classes (they called them "ranges" in the above) and quantifiers, but if they don't support alternations, they don't support alternations. :-|

Comment: Yes, will try to convert the regex into an array and then loop over each element to dynamically create the rules! Thanks for your time!

Comment: @flo: No worries, hope that helped. :-)